# Setting filter value in Core Image is causing a crash. - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, filter, core-image, setvalue

What I am trying to do is take a screenshot, crop that screenshot, and then to make it look better by apply the CISharpenLuminance filter. The code has all worked fine until I add the filter. When I push the button that does all of this I get this error: "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" and a crash error in the first line of the AppDelegate with the message: "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Here is my code:

```
        //Getting the Image
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
        view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        //Cropping the Image
        let rect = CGRectMake(0, 97, 320, 213)
        let cgiImage = image?.CGImage
        let imageBitMap: CGImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(cgiImage, rect)



        //Sharpening the Image
        let ciiCroppedImage = CIImage(CGImage: imageBitMap)

        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISharpenLuminance")
        filter.setValue(ciiCroppedImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter.setValue(0.8, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)

        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
        let cgimg = context.createCGImage(filter.outputImage, fromRect: filter.outputImage.extent())

        finalImage = UIImage(CIImage: filter.outputImage)
```

If I comment this line out:
    filter.setValue(0.8, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
The app doesn't crash, but of course that kind of ruins the point. I am pretty sure that line is the problem, but I could be wrong. image and finalImage are declared as empty variables outside of the button. This is my first time working with Core Image so I don't exactly know what I'm doing, so its very possible this is a simple mistake. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use not kCIInputIntensityKey  param but [@"inputSharpness" or kCIInputSharpnessKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CISharpenLuminance)

[image]

So your code should be

```
filter.setValue(0.8, forKey: @"inputSharpness")
```

or

```
filter.setValue(0.8, forKey:kCIInputSharpnessKey)
```